# Using a loop with sample() based on conditions in dataframe

Tags: r, random, conditional-statements, sample

I have a dataset with dates generated from this code:

```
library(chron)
dates <- seq.dates("1/1/2019", "1/6/2020", by = "days")
week <- c(1:53)
day <- c("tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday", 
"monday")
weeks <- rep(1:53, each = 7)
dates_df <- data.frame(date=dates, day=day, week=weeks)
```

And I'm trying to use a loop with sample() to randomly select 3 days from each week without replacement but I can't seem to find a way to indicate in my loop that I need to sample 3 times for every integer in dates_df$week then move to the next week.

I can't simply sample on a set sequence (7 days for instance) because on an actual calendar some months end in the middle of the week.

Is there a way to use sample() conditionally based on other values in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`sample_n`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample.html) and [`group_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) from the [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) package:

```
library(dplyr)

dates_df %>%
    group_by(week) %>%
    sample_n(3)

#    date        day        week
#    <S3: dates> <fct>     <int>
#  1 01/03/19    thursday      1
#  2 01/07/19    monday        1
#  3 01/04/19    friday        1
#  4 01/10/19    thursday      2
#  5 01/08/19    tuesday       2
#  6 01/13/19    sunday        2
#  7 01/16/19    wednesday     3
#  8 01/17/19    thursday      3
#  9 01/21/19    monday        3
#  ....
```

For each week, the `sample_n` function will pick three dates. The default for `sample_n` is to sample without replacement.

Here's a base `R` solution using `by`:

```
do.call('rbind', # bind by row
        by(dates_df, dates_df$week, # split data by week
           FUN = function(d) d[sample(nrow(d), 3),])) # sample

#            date       day week
# 1.5    01/05/19  saturday    1
# 1.3    01/03/19  thursday    1
# 1.7    01/07/19    monday    1
# 2.13   01/13/19    sunday    2
# 2.9    01/09/19 wednesday    2
# 2.8    01/08/19   tuesday    2
# ...
```